# Add Button should seen if the field has any data? onkeyup fuction is not triggering everytime.my purpose is to create a to do list

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

One input field is default.clicking add button will attach new input fields.

```html
    
          <div>
          <ul id="new">
            <li id="try"><input type="checkbox"><input class="set field" name="list" type="text" value=""></li>
         </ul>
          </div>     
          <div>
            <button id="btn1">add</button>
            <button id="btn2" type="submit" value="submit">Save</button>
```

first time onkeyup function is working but after that it is not triggering

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btn1').hide();
             $('.field').on('keyup',function(){
      
             var search_text = $('.field').val();
           if(search_text==""){
   
            $('#btn1').hide();

          }else{
          $('#btn1').show();
          }
          });
          $("#btn1").click(function () {
                var x = 1;
                event.preventDefault();
                x++;   
                $('#new').append('<li id="try"><input type="checkbox"><input name="list[]" class="set field" type="text" value=""></li>');  
          $('#btn1').hide();
             
           });
           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating elements you should always give them unique IDs if you are using them. Adding elements with the same ID will cause conflicts and unexpected behaviour.

```
<div>
    <ul id="new">
        <li id="try-0"><input type="checkbox"><input class="set field" name="list" type="text" value=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>     
<div>
    <button id="btn1">add</button>
    <button id="btn2" type="submit" value="submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

Your main errors were

1. Not having unique IDs and

   2.Your key up event didn't accommodate for dynamically created elements.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var x = 1; // Set to 1 on document load, not every add
       $('#btn1').hide();
       $('body').on('keyup', '.field', function(){
           var search_text = $('.field').last().val(); //finds last added .field and checks if blank
           // this allows other inputs to have their values changed while not triggering the show button
           if(search_text==""){
               $('#btn1').hide();
           }else{
               $('#btn1').show();
           }
       });
       $("#btn1").click(function (event) { //need to pass event if you want to use it
           event.preventDefault();  
           $('#new').append('<li id="try-'+x+'"><input type="checkbox"><input name="list[]" class="set field" type="text" value=""></li>');
           // ID now contains x variable that increments every add 
           $('#btn1').hide();
           x++; // increment x now at bottom so increments after field has been added.    
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="new">
    <li id="try"><input type="checkbox"><input class="set field" name="list" type="text" value=""></li>
</ul>
<button id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" hidden="">Save</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("input[name='list']").keyup(function(event) {
  if($(this).val() != ""){
    $("#btn").show();
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(event) {
    var val = '';
    var val = $("input[name='list']").val();
    $("#try").before('<li>'+val+'</li>');
    $("input[name='list']").val("");
    $("input[name='list']").removeAttr('value');
    $("#btn").hide();
});
</script>
```